# How to make the StreamReader read from the start of the textfile

Tags: c#, streamreader

I have created a streamReader, but the first 'ReadLine()' reads the 14th line in the file, not the first, and I don't know why this is.

My code is:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("argus-BIG.txt");  

//create array to hold data values
string[] branchData = new string[11];

//get 11 lines of branch data file and store in an array
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
{
    branchData[i] = reader.ReadLine();
}            

//new instance of Branch Class
Branch tempBranch = new Branch();

//set branch values from branchData array
tempBranch.setBranchID(branchData[0]);
tempBranch.setBranchNickname(branchData[1]);
tempBranch.setBranchAddressNo(branchData[2]);
tempBranch.setBranchAddressStreet(branchData[3]);
tempBranch.setBranchAddressCity(branchData[4]);
tempBranch.setBranchAddressCountry(branchData[5]);
tempBranch.setBranchAddressPostCode(branchData[6]);            
tempBranch.setNearestBranch1(branchData[7]);
tempBranch.setNearestBranch2(branchData[8]);
tempBranch.setNearestBranch3(branchData[9]);
tempBranch.setNoCategories(Convert.ToInt32(branchData[10]));
```

---

I wrote a test app, which worked, then copied and pasted the code (which looked identical to me) back into my main program, and it worked. Thanks for your help

Comment: 'the first 'ReadLine()' reads the 14th line' - not with this code. Post full (real) code, write a small test app if you have to.

Comment: are you sure you are reading the right file? try reading the file with full path.

Comment: You also should be using `using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("argus-BIG.txt")){ ... }`

Comment: Can you post the file which you are reading? Might be file exist with out line break.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be working, and I am guessing that there is something else happening along the way. Once you open a reader, it moves down and must be reset if you want it back to reading from the top. Maybe your reference was left open elsewhere (but that is assuming that the posted code has something happening that was not posted), or used before this piece of code?

However, you can always [force the position to the top](http://occasional-solipsism.blogspot.com/2006/06/resetting-streamreader.html) to verify this theory. If after this code, you still are at the 14th line, then it might be the file itself somehow?

```
reader.DiscardBufferedData(); 
reader.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); 
reader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
```

Comment: The OP is _creating_ a fresh stream in the first line.

Comment: I wrote a test app, which worked, then copied and pasted the code (which looked identical to me) back into my main program, and it worked. Thanks for your help.